# find the percentage of Transactions paid in cash

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to find the % of transactions that were paid in cash. I have tried the query below but it's showing me each cash transaction line by line, is there anyway I can group this into a singular figure. Thank you

```
SELECT RTD, 
[tender_Amt],
[tender_Amt] * 100 / (SELECT SUM([tender_Amt]) AS s FROM [dbo].[Payments] ) AS Percentage_of_total 
FROM [dbo].[Payments]
where RTD='CASH';
```

Comment: Look up `conditional aggregation`

Comment: provide sample data and desired output

Answer (score 0):

Just use `avg()`:

```
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN RTD = 'CASH' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END) as avg_cash
FROM [dbo].[Payments];
```

If you wanted the ratio of each payment type:

```
SELECT RTD, COUNT(*) * 1.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER ()
FROM [dbo].[Payments]
GROUP BY RTD;
```

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure what do you need: you say % of transactions but query seems to be returning % of cash from the amount paid. So I did both

```
SELECT
       count(case when rtd = 'CASH' then 1 end) / count(1) * 100 Percentage_of_transactions,
       sum(case when rtd = 'CASH' then tender_Amt end) / sum(tender_Amt) * 100 Percentage_of_cash
  FROM [dbo].[Payments];
```